# Xfdesktop not showing custom action icons in thunar right click

Tags: xfce, thunar-custom-actions, xfdesktop

In xfce 4.14 i have several custom actions with custom icons. Actions works fine in right click context menu but their icons not appear, except those from root path.

**My custom icons located in home directory.**

**The Thunar uca.xml config file looks fine without errors.**

**Os: Xubuntu 20.04**

How to display custom icons in right click menu?

Any help will be appreciated.